# In the movie The Aviator why does Howard Hughes like citrus?

Tags: the-aviator

I know I am probably reading too much into this but I thought it was a bit weird for a fully grown mature millionaire like Howard Hughes to say: Lil Howard likes citrus’ or something to that affect.

Was there a report meaning to this saying by Howard or did he simply just like orange juice?

Comment: [Howard Hughes was an odd-duck in the years leading up to his death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Hughes#Physical_decline).

Comment: When asking questions about biopics, you should probably research the subject of the film first.

Answer (score 4):

### Because Howard Hughes DID like orange juice

Although reclusive and eccentric in later years, Hughes was a big drinker of orange juice and believed that it has [great restorative powers](https://wujilife.com/blogs/wuji-life/howard-hughes-and-the-power-of-vitamin-c).

> Howard Hughes was an American aviator, filmmaker, inventor and business tycoon. He was one of the wealthiest people of his time. Hughes formed the Hughes Aircraft Company, which over the years produced 4 planes and numerous missiles and spacecraft. Hughes was fond of testing out his planes himself and it was said that he was an excellent pilot. However, Hughes went down with his plane on more than a few occasions. His last plane crash left him lucky to be alive.

> On July 8th 1946, The Leominster Daily(a local newspaper), had this to say, “His collarbone and seven ribs broken, his lungs punctured in six places, Howard Hughes was given a fighting chance to live today after crashing an experimental plane into three houses and a garage in Beverly Hills late yesterday…Hughes also suffered a broken nose, third degree burns on his hands, and possible skull and left leg fractures in the crash and explosion of his newest plane, the XF-11,  unofficially reported to be the fastest long-range craft ever constructed.”
>
> It was said to be a miracle that Hughes survived at all, yet after five weeks in the hospital Hughes walked himself out.
>
> **Hughes attributed this remarkable recovery to the gallons of fresh squeezed orange juice that he drank every day while in the hospital.**